# How to initially set the value in realm model property by [String] and call it to display?

Tags: swift, realm

I study realm and want to add initial values to the database and then display them with the ability to add them, but I don't understand how to set them at the beginning. An array can only be declared via @objc dynamic as far as I understand. But how to access this property and display all the names?

Example:

```
class Dog: Object {
    @Persisted var names = ["Bob", "Charlie", "Puppy"] // But it is not works
    @objc dynamic var names = ["Bob", "Charlie", "Puppy"]

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no arrays in Realm. Realm uses [Collections](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/model-data/define-model/supported-types/#key-concept--collection-types) such as Results and Lists which have some similar functions to arrays but they are not the same

In this use case you should probably define names as a List

```
class Dog: Object {
   @Persisted var names = List<String>()
}
```

and then once the Dog object is instantiated, populate the names property

```
let d = Dog()
d.names.append(objectsIn: ["Bob", "Charlie", "Puppy"])
```

This syntax `@objc dynamic` is older and while is still valid, please move to the more current syntax of `@Persisted`

Comment: But what if I have a permanent list of names and I want it to be always displayed, but so that the user can add more names?

Comment: @S1mpledev Great question. There are a number of ways to do that but the details will depend on your specific use case. As shown in the answer, you could, on app start, create a Dog and add the names to it - there would only ever be one dog but adding names to that dog would be easy. - OR - when the Realm object is instantiated, use a convenience init to populate the dog list (assuming every object has the same list). There are a number of other solutions as well. Now you know the basics, if you have more details it may be a good idea to open a separate question.